# Return Ok() from Exception filter .net framework

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a generic exception handler in .NET framework 4.7 where I identify each type of exception to generate logs. However I do not want to throw the exception but once the log is done I want to return a code 200 `Ok()` from the exception handler Is it possible to do that?

```
public class GlobalExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext exceptionContext)
    {
        if (exceptionContext.Exception is DALException)
        {
            //log               
        }
        else if (exceptionContext.Exception is BLLException)
        {
            //log
        }
        else
        {
            //log
        }

        ThrowOkResult();
    }

    public IHttpActionResult ThrowOkResult()
    {
        GenericResponse exceptionResponse = new GenericResponse()
        {
            Code = 500,
            Message = "the request could not be processed"
        };

        return Ok(exceptionResponse); //The name "Ok" does not exist in the current context
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> The name "Ok" does not exist in the current context

I know that it should return an exception but, in this case I need to return an OK, is it possible?

Comment: You mention **.NET 4.7**, but you tag the question with ` asp.net-core` - those are **not** the same - which one are you really using? The "classic", full .NET Framework (v4.7) - or the newer **.NET Core** ? (and if so: which version of .NET Core?)

Comment: .net framework 4.7.2

Comment: `Ok` is a `ControllerBase` method that returns an `ActionResult` instance whose status is 200. Yo'll have to construct this instance yourself. You should *really* rethink this though. Lying to the client is a bad idea. A 200 response containing some custom response with a 500 code is still a Success, not a failure response. It would be better to return a proper response with a 500 and a custom message or a `ProblemDetails` result with any information you want to send to the client